# cygwin gdb creating stackdump in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb, g++, cygwin

When I debug a simple hello world program using cygwin gdb it works fine but when I debug it using emacs(for windows) using the argument:

```
gdb -i=mi test.exe
```

it gives the following error:

```
3 [main] gdb 6576 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gdb.exe.stackdump
```

The content of gdb.exe.stackdump:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00100427142
rax=00000006002CA300 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00000001801E5DA0
rdx=0000000000C3CE00 rsi=000000000000152C rdi=000000010092E770
r8 =0000000000000540 r9 =00000006002CA2F0 r10=0000000000C40000
r11=0000000100635B1C r12=0000000600244060 r13=00000000FFFFFFFF
r14=0000000000C38180 r15=00000000FFFFFFFF
rbp=000000000000152C rsp=0000000000C37F60
program=c:\cygwin64\bin\gdb.exe, pid 6576, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

If I debug simply by:

```
gdb test.exe
```

it works fine in cygwin terminal but in emacs it says:

```
Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!
```

Can anyone give me a workaround? I just want to debug c++ files using gdb in emacs on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I solved it with following guideline:

Use gcc, gdb x64, if you use emacs x64

Use gcc, gdb x32, if you use emacs x32